# How to make dim background when alert executed?

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone application in which in a button click i am showing a view like an alertview.at that time i want my remaining views (background) to be a shadow one,like as we see the background when showing the alertview.Can anybody help me to achieve this?

Comment: EXACT duplicate of another user's post. Why are you doing this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116241/how-to-make-my-background-view-to-be-dark-when-the-another-view-is-showing

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate because the UIAlertView dims the background with some gradient from the center to the edges... My advice is to download the source of `MBProgressHUD` and see how is implemented there, because it's almost the same as UIAlertView does it...

Comment: U can change the alpha value for the view that should be made dim or you can insert one more view with desired color/brightness..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a transparent background patch for this.